# What does it mean to return a value?

Tags: java, return-value, return

I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm confused about what it means exactly to return a value. At first, I thought it meant to output what value is being returned, but when I tried that in my own code, nothing happened.

```
class Class1 {

    public static int x = 3;

    public static int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Class1.getX();
    }
}
```

This is an example of what I mean. When I run the program, nothing shows up. Considering this, I'm led to believe returning a value means something else. But what?

Answer (score 7):

In simple terms, it means to return the value to caller of the method...

So, in your example, the method `getX` would return the value of `x` to the caller, allowing them access to it.

```
class Class1{

    static int x = 3;

    public static int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int myX = Class1.getX(); // return the value to the caller...
        System.out.println(myX); // print the result to the console...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also note that when you return, it exits the method.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a value is a way for methods to talk to each other

```
public void method1() {
    int value = 5 + method2(5);
    System.out.println(value);
}

public int method2(int param) {
    return param + 5;
}
```

This will print 15 (5 gets sent to `method2`, which adds 5 to it and returns the result to `method1`, which adds 5 to it and prints the result).

Java returns copies of values - in this case, it's copying the value `10` and returning it to `method1`.  If `method2` were returning an `Object` then it would return a copy of the object's reference.  Different languages have different semantics for method returns, so be cautious when switching between languages.  Java also copies the values of parameters passed to methods - in this case `method1` copies the value 5 and passes it to `method2`.

```
public void method1() {
    int value = 5;
    method2(value);
}

public void method2(int param) {
    param = param + 5;
}
```

The `value` in `method1` is unaffected by `method2` (`value` still equals 5 after `method2` executes), because only a copy of `value` was sent as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. So if I understand correctly, method2, whose argument equals 5 by declaration inside method1, adds 5 to the original argument, and then replaces the original argument with 10?

Comment: Yes, just remember that method2 only sees a **copy** of the argument passed from method1; the value of `param` in method2 is changed to 10, but `value` in method1 is still equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling a method which returns an integer but you are never using/printing it. Try to use it in your code to see whether you have got the desired value as you have set in your class.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that you invoke a function (any function) and the result of the function is passed back to the code that called it.

For example if you have a method called add and you invoke that method the value returned will be assigned to the calling code, please see the example below.

```
public class Main { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        // Function add is called with two values and the result is assigned to 
        // the variable z
        int z = add(a, b); 
        System.out.println("The sum of a and b is: " + z);
        }

    static int add(int a, int b){
        int z = a+b;
        return z;

    }
}
```