# Send Array back to main method

Tags: java, methods, process

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] ar = new Integer[] { 5, 2, 1, 12, 2, 10, 4, 13, 5 };
    processD(ar);

    System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(ar));
}
```

I am basically trying to move `Integer[]` to the method `processD` and then print back the output through the main method. I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I know most of the program works because if I put the print command in the `processD` function it works perfectly. But in the main method it just prints the input without processing it. Any help willl be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class MethodBeta {

  public static void processD(Integer[] iA) {

    int[] array = new int[iA.length];
    for (int u = 0; u < iA.length; u++) {
      array[u] = iA[u].intValue();
    }
    // If array is smaller than 2 then already sorted
    if (array.length < 2) {
      return;
    }

    // create sub-arrays and keep multiplying by 2 to increase their number
    int z1 = 1;
    int z2, z3;

    while (z1 < array.length) {
      z2 = 0;
      z3 = z1;

      while (z3 + z1 <= array.length) {

        merge(array, z2, z2 + z1, z3, z3 + z1);
        z2 = z3 + z1;
        z3 = z2 + z1;
      }
      if (z3 < array.length) {
        merge(array, z2, z2 + z1, z3, array.length);
      }
      z1 *= 2;
    }
  }

  public static void merge(int[] ar1, int startL, int stopL, int startR, int stopR) {

    int[] right = new int[stopR - startR + 1];
    int[] left = new int[stopL - startL + 1];

    for (int i = 0, k = startR; i < (right.length - 1); ++i, ++k) {
      right[i] = ar1[k];
    }
    for (int i = 0, k = startL; i < (left.length - 1); ++i, ++k) {
      left[i] = ar1[k];
    }

    right[right.length - 1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    left[left.length - 1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int z = startL, x = 0, y = 0; z < stopR; ++z) {
      if (left[x] <= right[y]) {
        ar1[z] = left[x];
        x++;
      } else {
        ar1[z] = right[y];
        y++;
      }
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] ar = new Integer[] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 10, 4, 13, 5 };
    processD(ar);
    System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(ar));
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to return a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312323/what-does-it-mean-to-return-a-value)

Comment: What do you do in `processD(ar);`? Can you show it?

Comment: I need to add the print function inside the main method.. what would be the best way to achieve this then? and processD is basically a sorting process through the array...

Comment: @AndrewLi The value of an object is its reference. Integer[] works the same way so I believe the actual array will be changed?

Comment: I think a problem might be somewhere here: public static void mergeSortB(Integer[] inputArray){
  
  int[] array = new int[inputArray.length];
  for (int m = 0; m < inputArray.length; m++) 
  {
   array[m] = inputArray[m].intValue();
  }

Comment: "processD is basically a sorting process through the array..." Just post the content of this method, will you? If there's a bug, very likely is there. ** Post it in your question, not comments **

Comment: I am not sure how I can do that in the comments...

Comment: Under your question, there's a small link named "edit". Click on it an put that code in.

Comment: Found it thanks! Also I cannot change the signature for process D or main... I think the problem really is in the conversion from Integer[] to int[] because before that the code worked perfect.(the first few lines of processD)

Comment: @YuanGuo I'll just give you a quick fix as I don't really have the time to construct a beautiful answer. Add `iA = array;` at the very last line in the method 'processD()' and change all 'int' to 'Integer'

Comment: @YuanGuo note that my quick fix is a really dirty and horrible way of doing things. Hopefully someone will provide a complete answer

Comment: @akgren_soar Have you noticed the " Also I cannot change the signature for process D or main" comment?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Thanks, I totally missed that. Modified my quick fix to fit requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `public static void processD(Integer[] iA)` - copies the value in a local `array` variable, does all the work on that local variable, but **never copies back the values in the `iA` parameter**

Of course the `iA` parameter remains unchanged.

Once you are done, at the end of the method, simply:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  iA[i]=array[i];
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I fix it? Like move the local array back to the main method? or copy the values back in the iA? Thank you..

Comment: @YuanGuo there.

Comment: thank you for your help! Just one question; will this be accounted as an in place sorting? The question I mean

Comment: @YuanGuo "will this be accounted as an in place sorting?" Nope. Because the first two lines in the merge method are `int[] right = new int[stopR - startR + 1];
    int[] left = new int[stopL - startL + 1];` - those `new int` suddenly make the method "with additional space"